# InlineEditSupport not working

Tags: visualforce, jquery, pageblocktable, inline-visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I'am using `apex:inlineEditSupport` in a visualforce page, the `apex:inlineEditSupport` is used inside a `pageblocktable` tag with the pagination provided by the `pageblockTable`.

The visualforce page is a inline visualforce page on Campaign object.

Inline editing works for the data present on the first page of the table but as soon as we change the page number of the table, the data is populated correctly but the inline editing is not present for the data to be updated and when we switch back to the first page the inline editing is present.
Also, jquery datatable is used to provide pagination to the table.

Why is this happening and what can we do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the VF page code?

Comment: Just found that, when the page number changes (ie, from 1 to any other) so on hovering over the column value to edit, a class is put in the html span which is "inlineEditWrite" . This works fine for the first page but on the second page this class if appended by ' ' because of which the class added on hovering has a ' ' in between.

Comment: How did you solve? I mean what is the code change here

Comment: @JiteshGoel you able to fix this issue ?